# I want `WHERE IN` to return 0 if an `IN` field does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider the query:

```
SELECT id, count(id) AS "count"
FROM table
WHERE id IN (
    'value1',
    'value2',
    'value3'
)
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY count ASC;
```

If each of those `IN` values are present in `table`, then I'd get a result as such:

```
RESULTS
-------
value1    <value>
value2    <value>
value3    <value>
```

But if, say, `value2` was not present in `table`, then I'd get

```
RESULTS
-------
value1    <value>
value3    <value>
```

Notice the absence on `value2` in the results.

**I'd like to have `value2` displayed with a value of `0`.**

For context, I have a table of Rep IDs associated with Subscription IDs.  And I want to query this to get the Rep with the least amount of Subscriptions.  The issue is that the Rep IDs in this table are not exhaustive.  So, I programmatically query a separate datasource that contains the exhaustive list of Rep IDs.  My idea is to somehow create a query, using that exhaustive list of Rep IDs, to get the desired response I mentioned above.

Does anyone have any ideas for this?  I've seen similar postings about this where the solution was to use `COALESCE`, but my subquery returns more than one result, which caused PostgreSQL to burp.

Comment: The easiest way would be to get your exhaustive list into the same database as your other table, then it's just a left join.

Comment: can't i create a temp table somehow in the same query?  using `with` or something of that nature?

Comment: you can also build the list like `with t (id) as (select 'value1' union all select 'value2' union all select 'value3')`

Comment: dang it!  that was my first attempt, but i forgot to `union all`, so they manifested as columns.  thanks for the update, very useful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build up a list that you can outer join to with a `values()` clause:

```
SELECT d.id, count(t.id) AS "count"
FROM (
  values 
    ('value1'),
    ('value2'),
    ('value3')
) as data (id)
  left join the_table t on t.id = d.id
GROUP BY d.id
ORDER BY count ASC;
```

Note that you must use `count(t.id)` (counting values from the joined table) to get the count of 0

Alternatively you can use a common table expression if you don't want to clutter the `from` part with the `values` clause:

```
with data (id) as (
  values 
    ('value1'),
    ('value2'),
    ('value3')
)
SELECT d.id, count(t.id) AS "count"
FROM data d
  left join the_table t on t.id = d.id
GROUP BY d.id
ORDER BY count ASC;
```

Comment: are you a wizard?!  thank you, that's exactly what i wanted. the `values` statement is new to me; i had been trying to use a `with` clause, but neglected to give the values a column name, and didn't use the `values` statement.  also, i like the second solution better, just reads cleaner to me.  are there any caveats you know of in using one of those solutions versus the other?

Comment: @liltitus27: both solutions are identical in terms of performance. I too prefer the version with a CTE because the actual query isn't cluttered with the `values` clause.

Comment: @liltitus27 Don't forget to accept a_horse_with_no_name's answer if he helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can build up the missing value using below query...test it out. 
Hope I understand your question correctly.

```
DROP TABLE TEST2
GO
CREATE TABLE TEST2(ID INT, M1 INT)
GO
INSERT INTO TEST2 VALUES (1,20)
INSERT INTO TEST2 VALUES (2,25)
INSERT INTO TEST2 VALUES (3,30)
GO
SELECT * FROM TEST2 
GO
SELECT CONVERT(INT,B.N) AS NB, A.M1  FROM TEST2 A RIGHT JOIN
(

SELECT TOP (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TEST2) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number) FROM [master]..spt_values AS A 
 ) B
 ON A.ID = B.n 

GO
DELETE FROM TEST2 WHERE ID =2
GO

SELECT CONVERT(INT,B.N) AS NB, A.M1  FROM TEST2 A RIGHT JOIN
(

SELECT TOP (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TEST2) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number) FROM [master]..spt_values AS A 
 ) B

 ON A.ID = B.n
```

Comment: This is invalid for Postgres