# SQL List with empty items

Tags: sql

I have to search a table ("NamesAges") for the names and ages of a set of names. The problem is that the table has thousands of names, the set of names that I am searching with has hundreds and not all the names in the set are in the table. How can I get an explicit NULL entry for the missing names.

Specifically:

```
NamesAges
=========
Allan 44
Brenda 33
Carl 21
Daniel 34
```

Set of Names == (Allan, Bonita, Chandra, Daniel)

I can do:

```
SELECT Name, Age
FROM [NamesAges]
WHERE Names IN ('Allan', 'Bonita', 'Chandra', 'Daniel')
```

but I want to get some indication that Bonita and Chandra are missing in the table.

Comment: Create a temp table containing all the names you are searching for. `LEFT JOIN` `NameAges` to your temp table. Then you'll get a null for the missing names.

Comment: The answer depends on your database engine, which you didn't specify.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36754896/330315

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
SELECT a.Name, b.Age, case when b.Name IS NULL THEN 'Missing' ELSE 'OK' End Status
FROM (
    SELECT 'Allan' Name 
    UNION SELECT 'Bonita' 
    UNION SELECT 'Chandra' 
    UNION SELECT 'Daniel'
) a
LEFT JOIN [NamesAges] b ON b.Name = a.Name
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your helpful responses.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the set of names is in another table, you could probably use a left join:

```
select s.name, n.age
from   set_of_names s
       left join names_and_ages n on s.name = n.name
```

This will give you all the names in the set of names, along with the age from the other table if it finds a name match (and null otherwise).

Answer (score -1):

If you are using one table, join the table on itself using a different handle for the second table.  This will work and will return `NULL` for everything that is not in the list that you are providing.  If you want your query manager to display the word `NULL`, you can modify settings to do that as well or you can write a `CASE` statement with `null` as the option when nothing returns.

```
select na1.NAME 
from NamesAges na1 
  right join NamesAges na2 
          on na1.name = na2.NAME 
         and na2.NAME in  ('Allan', 'Bonita', 'Chandra', 'Daniel')
```

Comment: What is the purpose of joining the table to itself?  This seems like it would fail for the same exact reason OP's query didn't work.

Comment: To use an outer join to get null fields.  It seems to be the easiest way.

Comment: When would it ever return a null?  If the names aren't in the table, they're not going to appear in the results, which is exactly the problem OP is trying to solve.  Joining the table to itself doesn't solve that.

Comment: Yes it does.  Empty fields are null fields in SQL. If you would like I could show you how to display word null in the Resultset. When someone wants a null field, it is empty, unless I am misunderstanding what you want.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, but you're literally just returning a bunch of null rows.  I don't think that's what OP wants - see the other solutions for examples that will actually return all of the names in the name set, along with their ages (or null for the age if the name doesn't exist in the table).

Comment: I think my solution is simpler, but I didn't include the word NULL or 'Missing'.  I could have done that with a CASE statement.

Comment: I think the problem with your solution is that it won't actually show the names that aren't found.  I expect OP wants something like (Allan 44, Daniel 34, Bonita null, Chandra null) as his result.  But I think yours would return (Allan 44, Daniel 34, null null, null null) as the result.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!